# I am not able to implement Manty to One relationship in developing a search in multiple attributes across multiple models. One to Many works

Tags: django, search

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SearchForm
from .models import Author, Book, BookProfile

def index(request):
   return render (request,'index.html')

def multiple_model_search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':       
        
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data.get('query')
            author_results = Author.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
            book_title = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
            book_profile = BookProfile.objects.filter(isbn__icontains=query)                    
           
            context = {
                'author_results': author_results,
                'book_title': book_title,
                'book_profile':book_profile,            
                }
            return render(request, 'search_results.html', context)
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'form': form})
```

#models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True,)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BookProfile(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    booktitle = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    page = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.isbn
```

#search_results.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  
 <h6>Your search result is: </h6>
  
    {% for author in author_results %}
        <li class="h4">{{ author.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
         
    {% endfor %}
 
   {% for book in book_title  %}
   <li>{{book.title}}</li>
   <li>by: {{book.author}}</li>
   
   
   {% endfor %}
   

      {% for book in book_profile %}
      <li>{{ book.booktitle }}</li>
      <li>{{ book.author}}</li>
      <li>{{ book.isbn }}</li>
         
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock  %}
```

#########################################################
I am doing a search app, that allows users to search books with their properties and authors. So it is " Multiple properties across multiple models". The problem is I can't bring the One-to-Many relationship search. The Many-to-one works. I want to retrieve books written by the one author. When I search book, It shows, the author, isbn, pages. But when I search author, cant get books.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Comment: Thanks for viewing my code. Here is edited, like you comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

To access the secondary model through the primary model: model name lowercase and _set prefix. If you specified related_name, then this will be what you specified in related_name.

Doc: [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)

for i in author.book_set.all():
    print(i)
```

And from the opposite we are looking for books by a certain author. In the secondary `Book` model, we use the `author` field associated with the primary model and write the `name` field of the primary model through a double underscore.

```
book_author = Book.objects.filter(author__name=author's name)
```